# syntax error, unexpected T_SWITCH in PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement

Here's the code:

```
<?php
    $r=rand(1,7) //get a random number from 1 to 7 inclusive...
    switch($r) { //...and get a random quote
    case 1:
    echo '<p class="quote">welcome to Moonside.<br/>Wecomel to Soonmide.<br/>Moonwel ot Cosidme.</p>';
    break;
    case 2:
    echo '<p class="quote">Hey! Parking Meters! And you\'re walking around!<br/>Ha ha ha... That\'s so funny.</p>';
    break;
    case 3:
    echo '<p class="quote">"Yes" is "No" and "No" is "Yes."<br/>It makes perfect sense in Moonside.</p>';
    break;
    case 4:
    echo '<p class="quote">Hello!<br/>And... good-bye!</p>';
    break;
    case 5:
    echo '<p class="quote">This is a headline from tonight\'s Moonside Press...<br/>\"Mani Mani is always Mani Mani at Mani Mani with all Mani Mani Mani."</p>';
    break;
    case 6:
    echo '<p class="quote">I can sense...that...you have a controller...in your...hands...</p>';
    break;
    case 7:
    echo '<p class="quote">Ness\'s HP drops to 0!<br/>Jeff\'s HP drops to 0!</p>';
    break;
    }
    ?>
```

If it could matter at all, I will mention that this whole PHP block is indented twice in my HTML source

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You forgot a semicolon earlier.

Comment: lol, stupid error, but make it too